# How to get user model validation errors to display inline with its corresponding form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

How can i get my user model validation errors to display inline with its corresponding form field (bootstrap and devise). As i am getting errors on top of the page "errors prohibited this user from being saved:
Fullname can't be blank
Phone number can't be blank
Date of birth must be at least 18 years old"
How can i get it next to corresponding line ?

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:confirmable

   validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 40}  
   validates :phone_number, presence: true, length: {maximum: 12} 
   validates :password,  :format => { :with => /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/,
   :message => "Password should contain at least 6 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric." }, on: :create
     validates :password,  :format => { :with => /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/,
   :message => "Password should contain at least 6 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric." }, on: :update, allow_blank: true

   validates_date :date_of_birth, :before => lambda { 18.years.ago },
                               :before_message => "must be at least 18 years old"

   has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


end
```

My html view file

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      </br>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-left">
     <div class="row">
          <label class="col-xs-4" for="fullname">Fullname</label>
              <div class="col-xs-8">    
                  <%= f.text_field :fullname, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Full Name', autofocus: true %>
              </div></br></br></br>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <label class="col-xs-4" for="Email1">Email</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Email' %>
            </div>
    </div></br>
    <div class="row">
                <label class="col-xs-4" for="phone_number">Phone Number</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <%= f.text_field :phone_number, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Phone Number', autofocus: true %>
                  </div>
            </div></br> 
      <div class="row">
                <label class="col-xs-4" for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                  <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, order: [:day, :month, :year], :start_year=>1910 %>
                  </div>
              </div></br>


       <div class="row">
           <% if @validatable %>
                      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                  <% end %>
              <label class="col-xs-4" for="password">Password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-8">                 
                  <%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Password',  autocomplete: "off" %>
                </div>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I would recommend you use gems like simple_form, they will take care of such requirement.

Comment: Can it support with devise as how can i replace this line   <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Simple-Form-with-Devise

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start by taking a look at the [`simple_form`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem which does just this and has ready made wrappers for Bootstrap.

If you for some reason still want to roll your own you need to check if the object wrapped by the form builder has errors which correspond to that field:

```
<div class="row">
  <% if f.object.errors[:full_name] %>
    <ul>
      <% f.object.errors[:full_name].each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Of course doing this for every row is really tedious so you may want to declare a helper method or create your own form builder class.

```
class MyFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def row_for_field(field, options = {})
    errors = @object.errors[field]
    row_classes = ['row']
    row_classes << 'invalid' if errors.any?
    @tempate.content_tag(:div, class: row_classes) do
      if errors.any?
        @tempate.content_tag(:ul, class: 'errors') do
          errors.each do |msg|
            @tempate.content_tag(:li, msg)
          end
        end
      end
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

You would then do:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)), form_builder: MyFormBuilder do |f| %>
  <%= f.row_for_field :fullname do  %>
    <%= f.text_field :fullname %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But then again - use simple_form. The whole reason to use bootstrap is spend your time on other things than the frontend.

Comment: PS. Don't use `placeholder` attributes as a replacement for labels! Its a serious accessibility problem. https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/